# Destination City using Arrays

Tags: javascript

I have randomized flight paths these arrays can be in order or out of order and my goal is to find the destination city.

my input is `paths = [["London", "New York"], ["New York", "Lima"], ["Lima", "Sao Paulo"]]`

my desired output is "Sao Paulo"
my first nested for loop is to check if the flight has a start and a stoping point (as Sao Paulo does not have a stopping point)

My current code is bellow:

```
var destCity = function(paths) { 
let truePath = [];
let  answer = "";
    
// finds verified paths first two for loops are to find and compare all trips  starting and and a stopping points and the if statment is there to take the trips that have a starting and stopping point that corispond to another flight and log them into a new array called truePath
for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j< paths[i].length; j++) {
        if (paths[i][1] == paths[j][0]) {
            truePath.push(paths[i][1]);
            //should return [New York, Lima] but only returns [New York]
        return truePath;
        }
    }
}



//tests for destination using verified paths, these for loops are for comparing the truePath array with the final desination of each flight. if the truePath array containes the starting desination of the final desination then then the answer = the final desination   
for (let k = 0; k < paths.length; k++) {
    for (let l = 0; l < paths.length; l++) {
        if (truePath[k] == paths[l][0]) {
            answer = paths[l][1].toString();
            break;
        }
    }

}
    
};
```

when I return my truePath/ my verified paths I only get [New York]. How can I get it to return [New York, Lima] or any paths that have a start and a destination?

Comment: please add input and wanted output.

Comment: The array you show has start point London and end point Sao Paolo, if you wrote this code: can you explain what each line does, according to you? (in the post, not as a comment) And of course not as "this line compares two array positions" but explaining why that line is there and what result it's effecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could take two loops, one for adding a value to a hash and another to find an unballanced positive value.

```js
function findDestination(paths) {
    const cities = {};
    
    for (const [departure, arrival] of paths) {
        cities[departure] = (cities[departure] || 0) - 1;
        cities[arrival] = (cities[arrival] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return Object.keys(cities).find(city => cities[city] === 1);
}

console.log(findDestination([["London", "New York"], ["New York", "Lima"], ["Lima", "Sao Paulo"]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a *destination* city that is not present in the *origin* position of any of the arrays.

So, create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all the origin cities. Then `find` the array in `paths` whose destination is not present in the origin set.

```js
const paths = [["London", "New York"], ["New York", "Lima"], ["Lima", "Sao Paulo"]],
      origins = new Set(paths.map(p => p[0])),
      output = paths.find(p => !origins.has(p[1]))[1]

console.log(output)
```